# The keyboard is coming upon the EditText field & thus hiding it. How to prevent the keyboard from hiding the EditText field?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

My EditText is at the bottom of screen, so when I'm tapping on it to edit it, the keyboard is hiding it. I want that when I tap on EditText, the keyboard should remain below it & should not hide it.

Here's the link to the screenshot showing EditText before tapping on it: http://imgur.com/cgme1HT

Here's the link to the screenshot after tapping on EditText (*the EditText field is below the keyboard now*): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB8Zm.jpg

**Here's my SettingUpUserProfile.java file's code**:

```
public class SettingUpUserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST = 0;
    public static final int PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 2;
    String imgDecodableString;
    protected ImageView userProfilePicture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_up_user_profile);

        userProfilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
        userProfilePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingUpUserProfile.this);
                builder.setTitle(null);
                builder.setItems(R.array.pickImage_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent intentCaptureFromCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(intentCaptureFromCamera, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Intent chooseFromGalley = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                chooseFromGalley.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(chooseFromGalley, PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

**Here's my activity_setting_up_user_profile.xml file's code**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_purple"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.SettingUpUserProfile">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userProfilePicture"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_number_edit_text_design"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/hint_userName"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#E0E0E0"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAllSet"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button_allSet"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/light_purple"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I really have no clue about what to do here!

Please let me know.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so please cooperate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use a ScrollView as the parent view in your xml file\

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where the softkeyboard was on top of the EditText views which were placed on the bottom of the screen. I was able to find a solution by adding a single line to my AndroidManifest.xml file's relevant activity.
Put layout inside a ScrollView.

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
This is how the whole activity tag looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.my.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

Here the most important value is the adjustResize. This will shift the whole UI up to give room for the softkeyboard.

Comment: This is somehow working, but the EditText is scrolling up almost after 4-5 mins of tapping on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Options-1**

Try using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**

**Options-2**

Use `ScrollView` as parent in xml. Replace your xml with this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.SettingUpUserProfile" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_purple">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userProfilePicture"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_number_edit_text_design"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/hint_userName"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#E0E0E0"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAllSet"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button_allSet"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/light_purple"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is there any error with the code or just not working ?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts bro, but it is still not happening!

Comment: Ok last thing, is the activity mode landscape?

Comment: No, it is portrait.
The problem now is that the first time I'm tapping on EditText, it is scrolling up. But after pressing back button & tapping on EditText again, it isn't scrolling up!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `ScrollView` as the parent view in your **xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.SettingUpUserProfile" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_purple" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/phone_number_edit_text_design"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/hint_userName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#E0E0E0"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAllSet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/button_allSet"
                android:textColor="@color/light_purple"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This did the work, but the bottom view has been destroyed now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

I solved the problem by changing my activity_setting_up_user_profile.xml file's code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_purple"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.SettingUpUserProfile" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/settingUpUserProfileText2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settingUpUserProfileText2"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/phone_number_edit_text_design"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/hint_userName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#E0E0E0"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAllSet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/button_allSet"
                android:textColor="@color/light_purple"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**This was COOL!**